# facebook php sdk response error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

In the following code.

```
$data = $facebook->api( '/'.$fbuid.'/likes', 'GET', array( 'access_token' => $access_token ));<br />
$data1 = $facebook->api( '/'.$fbuid.'/groups', 'GET', array( 'access_token' => $access_token ) );
$user_data = array_merge($data['data'], $data1['data']);
echo json_encode($data1['data']);
```

`$data1['data']` shows an empty array (sometimes).

`$user_data` only contains array conrtains data of of only `$data['data']`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way of getting that type of data:

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
. "client_id=" . $appId . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirectUri   //change with your data
. "&client_secret=" . $appSecret . "&code=" . $code;        

$response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
if($response) {
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    if(isset($params['access_token']) && $params['access_token']) {
        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
        . $params['access_token'];
        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
        if(isset($user)){ // you can do some isset verification
            var_dump($user); //you can check all data with this           
        print $user->name; // this prints guy's name          
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, it worked, but what't the problem in my code!